Lifecycle script 'build' failed with errors: npm build error
error message
I am getting this error not sure why ? In morning when I created build it was working and in afternoon I was facing this issue. while I run npm build first time I saw texted that npm patch version 10.5.2 is available for npm 10.5.0.
but i am not sure because of that this issue is coming.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue ?
I tried npm install,npm update, deleted node modules and again npm install,compared files with my local system's project which is working also checked google and some says memory could be the issue.
here's the snapshot of memory using command free -h
free -h
and here's snapshot of command top
top
